# External Hard drive usb port damaged

Tags: external-hard-drive

My external hard drive's USB port is damaged.
[image: picture of an HDD with a broken USB connector directly on the PCB]

I can't connect with my pc even I tried with mobile cable because it is USB 3.0 and also compatible with USB 2.0. when I connect only the light comes on.

Please tell me the alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at you picture that is an external drive with a direct USB interface. And the connector is dammaged.

This means you have two options:

1. It is broken. Throw it away. (Optionally buy a new one and copy data to that from backups).
2. Take it to someone who knows how to solder and have her fix the USB plug. Possibly replacing it with a new one. Do not try this yourself if you do not have experience with a soldering iron.

Note that this is a hardware problem on the drive's side. Changing cables, protocols or operating systems will not help. Basically the connector is broken and you must fix the connector.